# Same content on 2 worksheets with different filters.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to have always the same content on two worksheets within the same book. The purpose of it is that I want to have different filters on the second worksheet. Is important that if I add row in the middle of the first worksheet, it is also added on the second and based on their valie, it gets filtered accordingly.

I tried selecting all and Ctrl+C on my first worksheet and copy special as a link. But then, if you add a row on the first worksheet it wont be added on the second.

There is an easy way to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in A1 of your sheet1:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,ROW(),COLUMN())
```

And fill enough of the cells to cover all the additions you will need.  Now it is not dependent on sheet 2

Comment: It is hard to spot your typo but should that be 1048**57**6?

Comment: Yes it should. Thanks

Comment: Hey I think it will work perfectly, there is a way I can identify the empty spots and remove the "0"s ? I was going to use a "IF" but then I figure it out that if I naturally have a  "0" in my original sheet, I wouldn't like to remove that zero.. Anyway, I think I am close now.

Comment: `=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,ROW(),COLUMN())="","",INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,ROW(),COLUMN()))` @MXTEX

Comment: Opps, you were faster than me. Thanks Scott!! Any difference if I use your approach or IF(ISBLANK...) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Indirect()`.

Say your `Sheet1` is where you want the data to show, based on how you have `Sheet2` filtered, put this formula in `Sheet 1 A1` and drag over and down:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4))<>"",INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4)),"")
```

Comment: I was thinking more like Sheet1 will have all the data, no filters. Sheet 2 I will apply filters and on Sheet 3 the same but with different filters. I am making a product list, but depending on the machine to build diferent things will be selected.

Comment: @MXTEX - Then just adjust the `"Sheet2!"` part in the formula and it should be good.